# Phase Difference in mutual coupling

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, oscillators, electromagnetic-induction, electrical-engineering

I was reading about oscillator circuit then in my textbook it was written that we get phase change of π at mutual coupling.But, when I workout through mathematics of situation (which I have shown below) I get phase difference of π/2.(M is mutual inductance,i is amplitude of current in primary coil, $ε_o$ is emf induced in second coil).
$$i=iₒsin(ωt)$$
$$\phi=Misin(\omega t)$$
$$ε_o=-Mi(\omega)cos(\omega t)$$$$εₒ=Miωsin(ωt-π/2)$$

Please help me to figure out my mistake.[Circuit diagram](https://images.app.goo.gl/mUQNzhXfxUqTEn3t6)

Comment: The textbook talks about phase change in emf of first coil to emf in second and not current in first to emf in second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are mistaken in the language that book uses

That $\epsilon$(in your question) is the emf developed in second coil due to flux change in first, But what is the emf in the first coil that drives the current $I= i \sin(\omega t)$?Assuming pure inductive circuit(with no resistance) you can work out it to be $e_0 \cos(\omega t) $ where $e_0$ is the maximum value of emf of driving source

Now you can see a phase difference between emf in first to emf in second as $-\cos (\omega t) = \cos(\omega t + \pi)$

That is what your book should have meant

Comment: i think emf will be -ecos(wt) then phase diffrence is zero? can you explain this please

Comment: Why do you think so ? See [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/acind.html#c1) if current is varying with $sin(x)$ voltage is varying with $sin(x+\frac \pi 2)$ which is $cos (x)$ in inductive circuit.

Comment: sorry i did some math mistake.But once again thank you.